# MongoDB: find() query to select nothing

Tags: mongodb

What's an elegant way to set the *query* parameter so find() intentionally returns no documents?

Obviously I could just hardcode a query that I know would never return a result for my dataset. But that would be no fun.

Comment: The most elegant way to not return anything from a database is not to send a query to a database. There is a cost involved in asking for nothing as a result that you can avoid in your application by simply not sending the query.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @user3561036 good point. It's just a seldom running batch job, so not concerned about performance at all. Just wanted to neaten my code slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you won't gonna save *negative* `_id`. So you can try:

`db.collection.find({"_id":-1})`

Answer (score 3):

Query on `_id` field like following use any one of this :

```
db.collectionName.find({"_id":0})
db.collectionName.find({"_id":""})
db.collectionName.find({"_id":null})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar concern in that I want to build queries based on conditional logic. I could write full BSON for each condition but I think it makes the code less readable. What I ended up doing was using AND with a filters list

```
 List<Bson> filters=new ArrayList<>();
                filters.add(eq("title", job.getTitle()));
                filters.add(eq("companyName", job.getCompanyName()));
                if (job.getPostingDate() != null) {
                    filters.add(eq("postingDate", job.getPostingDate()));
                }

                if(job.getMinYearlySalary()!=null){
                    filters.add(eq("minYearlySalary", job.getMinYearlySalary()));
                }

                if(job.getMaxYearlySalary()!=null){
                    filters.add(eq("maxYearlySalary", job.getMaxYearlySalary()));
                }

                if(job.getMinHourlySalary()!=null){
                    filters.add(eq("minHourlySalary", job.getMinHourlySalary()));
                }

                if(job.getMaxHourlySalary()!=null){
                    filters.add(eq("maxHourlySalary", job.getMaxHourlySalary()));
                }

                Bson query=and(filters);
                CountOptions options = new CountOptions();
                options.limit(1);
                if (collection.countDocuments(query, options) > 0) {
                    containsJob = true;
                }
```

What I did is not the OPs exact question. I think this using an empty list would return everything but I have not tested it and could see it also returning nothing. That being said this approach will not waste time with pointless comparisons and is at least an interesting starting point.